# why does xml data parse as a string and not int

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

i have been trying to get my xml code to work on my python and after a few hours it did work but the next day when i re opened the codes, it didnt work. there was always a "not defined error" and now when i try to re do the codes, the data turns into a string?
this is the code that i have now (just a summary)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<settings>
    <standard name="max_days">90</standard>

    <standard name="min_days">7</standard>

    <standard name="warn_days">7</standard>
</settings>
```

and i parse my xml file like this:

```
file_name = ET.parse('imports.xml')
myroot = file_name.getroot()
for i in myroot[0]:
    print i.text
```

the problem is when i do the above, there will be no output at all not even an error but if i did

```
print myroot[0].text
```

it works but the data that i put is clearly an int so why is it a string when its parsed and whats the error?

Comment: You're iterating in `myroot[0]` instead of `myroot`. You can parse int: `int(i.text)`

Comment: i see.. i dont understand the difference becuase when i tried iterating in myroot[0] with a loop it works and then suddenly it doest.. very confusing